# Is there a way to prevent CHECKSTYLE:OFF being used

Tags: java, checkstyle

It's too easy for developers to drop `CHECKSTYLE:OFF` into code and ignore rules they shouldn't be ignoring, and it's too indiscriminate - it disables ALL the rules for that block, not just the ones they are trying to dodge.

Is there a way to disable the disablement, so that `CHECKSTYLE:OFF` does nothing, and style is always checked? Better yet, to flag up the use of `CHECKSTYLE:OFF` as an error. I'm open to using other plugins in the Maven build to do this if necessary.

Comment: Review the code before they submit it?

Comment: @AndyTurner What if the reviewer doesn't care? Automating these things is always preferable.

Comment: Automation is king. We do code reviews, and they do creep in depending on who signs off on the approvals - I've never been on a team were it's 100% of all reviewers required to merge, so it's usually "2 accepts / no declines". Automating the check will also help flush out the ones that slipped though and are already in the codebase too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [a module which is responsible for this](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_filters.html#SuppressionCommentFilter) which you are presumably including.

```
<module name="SuppressionCommentFilter"/>
```

Remove it from your checkstyle XML.

Comment: Bingo! Thank you. I searched for options in the Maven plugin but didn't think it would be a filter, and Google didn't help with any ideas at all. Hopefully this will help others too.